# JS check mutual items of 2 objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have 2 JS Objects:

The first one:

```
One = {
   "Sunday": {
      1:false,
      2:false,
      3:true,
      4:false, .... until 24. Each item could be either true or false.
   },
   "Monday": {1:true, 2:false, ....},
   //And so on, 7 days of the week
}
```

The second is just like the first one only its values (true/false) are different.

I want to run a function that can tell me, I don't care how, which items have `true` in both Objects. For example, if  `One.Sunday[2] = true` and `Two.Sunday[2] = true`, I want to know that.

I hope I was clear enough.

If possible it would be nice if that same function could accept 3 or more objects also and return the mutual items of **all** objects.

Thanks, Reuven

Comment: can you tell me how should your result look like ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Could be an object with arrays of the mutuals - `{"Sunday":[3, 4, 5, 9], "Monday:[1, 2, 7], and so on.}` But it's not critical. I just need it to be readable using JS

Comment: This is going to be more complicated than you probably think. Just comparing two object with a known structure isn't that hard, but when you have any number of objects which contains objects, and you're going to compare them all, you need somewhat complicated recursion etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sundayOne = {1:true,2:false,3:false,4:true}; 
var mondayOne = {1:true,2:true,3:false,4:false};
var tuesdayOne = {1:false,2:false,3:true,4:true};
var one = {"sunday":sundayOne,"monday":mondayOne,"tuesday":tuesdayOne}; // two objects having 


var sundayTwo = {1:true,2:true,3:true,4:true}; 
var mondayTwo = {1:false,2:false,3:false,4:false};
var tuesdayTwo = {1:true,2:true,3:true,4:true};
var two = {"sunday":sundayTwo,"monday":mondayTwo,"tuesday":tuesdayTwo};

var matchedArr = []
for(each in one) {
    var obj = {} //create new object
    obj[each] = {} //add new object to store matched each - Sunday, Monday
    for(subEach in one[each]) {
        //value is false so we have to check with undefined
        if(two[each][subEach] != undefined) {
            if(one[each][subEach] == two[each][subEach]) {
                console.log('Match found at ', each, subEach, one[each][subEach])
                obj[each][subEach] = one[each][subEach]
            }
        }
    }
    matchedArr.push(obj)
}
console.log(matchedArr)

//output
[Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
    sunday: Object
        1: true
        4: true
1: Object
    monday: Object
        3: false
        4: false
2: Object
    tuesday: Object
    3: true
        4: true
        length: 3
```

Comment: Looks great. I'm adapting it to my code right now, but by now it seems to work perfectly. +1 and +V and a **HUGE** thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the lovely response. Its more valuable than points. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got something working here for array of objects it will return a array of mutual.

Two Objects

```
var sunday = {1:true,2:false,3:false,4:true}; 
var monday = {1:true,2:true,3:false,4:false};
var tuesday = {1:false,2:false,3:true,4:true};
var one = {"sunday":sunday,"monday":monday,"tuesday":tuesday}; // two objects having 
var two = {"sunday":sunday,"monday":monday,"tuesday":tuesday};
```

Filtering Mutual :-

```
function getMutuals (objects) { //get an array of objects
    var mutuals = [];
    objects.forEach(function(obj,index){ 
       mutuals[index] = {};        
       for(var key in obj){
           mutuals[index][key] = [];  //it will create key like sunday,monday in each obj
           var day = obj[key];  // get that key
           for(var i=1;i<25;i++){  
               if(day[i])   //if day[i] is present
                   mutuals[index][key].push(i); //push that i into array of day
           }
       }
   });
   return mutuals;
}
```

you can call this function with arry of objects like following

```
var mutuals = getMutuals([one,two]);
console.log(mutuals)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function mutual(){
  var a = arguments, o = {};
  for(var i in a){
    var ai = a[i];
    out: for(var n in ai){
      o[n] = {}
      for(var q in ai[n]){
        if(!ai[n][q]){
          if(o[n][q]){
            delete o[n][q];
          }
          break out;
        }
        o[n][q] = true;
      }
    }
  }
  for(var i in o){
    var c = 0;
    for(var n in o[i]){
      c++;  
    }
    if(c === 0){
      delete o[i];
    }
  }     
  return o;
}
// assumes One, Two, Three, Four, Five are Objects
// use firebug for this console.log() or create loops
console.log(mutual(One, Two, Three, Four, Five));
```